# Eigenvalue of an element

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

what does it mean, if you say that $x$ is an eigenvalue of an element $g \in G$, where $G$ is a group? I know this definition just for matrices, not for elements.

Comment: Are you perchance considering group representations?

Comment: Yes I am. I have not expected it to refer just to representation theory. I will add this tag then too.

Comment: So, if you're given a representation $\phi:G\to {GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ or something of this nature, then a natural way to define an eigenvalues of $g\in G$ is to declare them to be the same as the eigenvalues of $\phi(g)$. However, this definition should depend on the representation. I'm pretty sure this is the correct idea, but I'm not super familiar with it can someone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a group representation $\rho: G\to GL(V)$ you have a matrix associated to every element $g\in G$, namely $\rho(g)$.